# How to listen self-hosted Azure Relay endpoint in both HTTP & HTTPS?

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

I'm trying to use Azure WCF Relays, creating my listener via a ServiceHost instance. It works well, but I can't make it work in both HTTP and HTTPS. I know it seems strange but that's a requirement I have.

Here is my code:

```
Uri httpUri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri(Uri.UriSchemeHttp, "MYNAMESPACE", "TEST");
Uri httpsUri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri(Uri.UriSchemeHttps, "MYNAMESPACE", "TEST");
WebServiceHost sh = new WebServiceHost(typeof(TestAPI), httpsUri, httpUri);
sh.Open();
```

And here is my conf:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpRelayBinding>
    <binding name="https" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" sendTimeout="00:15:00">
      <security mode="Transport" relayClientAuthenticationType="None"/>
    </binding>
    <binding name="http" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" sendTimeout="00:15:00">
      <security mode="None" relayClientAuthenticationType="None"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpRelayBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="TestAPI" behaviorConfiguration="default">
    <endpoint name="MobileEndpointHttps" contract="ITestAPI" binding="webHttpRelayBinding" bindingConfiguration="https" behaviorConfiguration="sbTokenProviderTest" address="" />
    <endpoint name="MobileEndpoint" contract="ITestAPI" binding="webHttpRelayBinding" bindingConfiguration="http" behaviorConfiguration="sbTokenProviderTest" address="" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="sbTokenProviderTest">
      <webHttp/>
      <serviceRegistrySettings discoveryMode="Public" />
      <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
        <tokenProvider>
          <sharedAccessSignature keyName="RootManageSharedAccessKey" key="MYKEY"/>
        </tokenProvider>
      </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="default">
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

The httpGetEnabled & httpsGetEnabled seems not required to make it work alone, so I disabled it to avoid the netsh warning.

With this config, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The ChannelDispatcher at 'sb://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/TEST/' with contract(s) '"ITestAPI"' is unable to open its IChannelListener. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: A registration already exists for
>   Uri 'sb://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/TEST/'.

Is it at least possible ? Need your help :(

Answer (score 0):

If you just create a single endpoint with security mode="None" and relayClientAuthenticationType="None" doesn't it accept traffic over both HTTP and HTTPS?